# Given date and day in week, find the closest date in future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given day in week (let's say Monday), I need to find closest date (in future) to given date (for example 9-4-2016) which is this day in week (for these examples, it should be 11-4-2016).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pure Ruby solution.

```
require 'date'

d = Date.strptime('9-4-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')
  #=> #<Date: 2016-04-09 ((2457488j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
d + (1 - d.wday) % 7
  #=> #<Date: 2016-04-11 ((2457490j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

`1` is Monday's offset. `d.wday #=> 6`.

I have assumed that if the date falls on a Monday, the "closest" Monday is the same day. If it is to be the following Monday, use:

```
d + (d.wday == 1) ? 7 : (1 - d.wday) % 7
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find this date in the nearest week of your `date`:

```
date =  Date.parse('9-4-2016')
(date..date + 6).find {|d| d.strftime("%A") == "Monday"}
#=> Mon, 11 Apr 2016
```

Comment: You really should use `strptime`, as `9` could be the day or month. Also, I suggest you include `require 'date'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it is question about Rails(according to tags), so no need to require it.